# An elegant way to get functions to run at specific time

Tags: powershell

I have a script with several functions that has to be executed at specific timeslots.
Function A needs to run every 15 sec.
Function B needs to run every minute.
Im doing this in an endless loop.

```
While ($true){
A
start-sleep -seconds 15
A
start-sleep -seconds 15
A
start-sleep -seconds 15
A
start-sleep -seconds 15
B
}
```

Now I need to start another function (C) every 10 sec.
This function is time consuming and My endless loop will move in the time slot.

I have an idea of executing the functions as jobs in parralell.
But how do I trig the job start at the right time with the right pause?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: why not make use of good old scheduled tasks? .. oh .. maybe that's not "elegant"?

Comment: Because this is in one Main script that is started in the task scheduler at startup. - And to keep an overview I don't want to build up a pile of scripts running in the task scheduler.

Comment: so maybe something like this? `while($true) {if((Get-Date).Second % 10){Start-Job -Name JobA};if((Get-Date).Second % 15){Start-Job -Name JobB}; Start-Sleep -Seconds 1}`

Comment: If the tasks aren't doing anything related you should stick to the "separation of concerns"-principle and run them independently in the task scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this code with a mixture from [Microsoft - Register-ObjectEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7) and [Mitzen.Blogspot](http://mitzen.blogspot.com/2017/01/powershell-creating-timer.html).

```
$timer = New-Object -TypeName System.Timers.Timer    
$Timer.Interval = 15000
$Timer.Autoreset = $True
$Timer.Enabled = $True
$timer.Start()

$objectEventArgs = @{
    InputObject = $Timer
    EventName = 'Elapsed'
    SourceIdentifier = 'Timer.Elapsed'
}
$action = {
    Write-Host -Object "Enter your function in this script block."
}

Register-ObjectEvent @objectEventArgs -Action $action
```